# Install ColdFusion Standard (2018) on CentOs 7.6 using command line

Tags: command-line, coldfusion, centos, installation

In the past, I have installed ColdFusion 9 on a CentOs server using command line, and it worked well, following these guides:

http://www.aaronwest.net/blog/index.cfm/2011/2/7/Super-Guide-Installing-ColdFusion-9-on-CentOS-Linux

http://wwvv.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/multi-cfml-engine-install-installing-cf9-on-linux-centos

This has been working well but we need to upgrade.

Now I need to install ColdFusion Standard (2018) on a CentOs 7.5 server with Apache 2.4

I have been looking and I don't find any guide to install it using command line. I need command line because I access server through terminal (PuTTY).

Has anyone done this? Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried already? Did something not work?

Comment: I need to know if this is possible before purchasing the new version of coldfusion. I am not finding any instructions on how this would be done.

Comment: You can download the developer edition for free. You can buy, eventually, when you are satisfied with the product. https://www.adobe.com/de/products/coldfusion-family.html

Comment: I too am looking for how to do this as well. I am wanting to install the dev (free) version of CF2018 into a VM on a Mac but the VM is Virtual Box within the VirtualHostX product from ClickOnTyler.com. It runs an Ubuntu linux server inside the Vbox VM. Only way to interact with it for adding this installation is using a terminal window it provides. So I too need a way to install CF2018 using a command line in a terminal. @Vero, Did you ever figure it out or get help?

Comment: No I didn't get any help yet.

Comment: @teaman and vero, did you make any progress with this? I've managed to install it fine (repeatedly) but I can't get the connector to work with Apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365989/coldfusion-2018-on-centos-7-failing-to-setup-apache-connector

Comment: @Pete No progress with it.