# Coldfusion 2018 on Centos 7 failing to setup Apache connector

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, centos

I've installing CF2018 on a new server, which is installed and running, I can see it if I run `ps aux | ack -i coldfusion`

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jul 29 2019 17:18:49
```

**UPDATE**

I had clearly broken something so I've removed earlier errors, but I'm still getting issues with the connector.

I have removed all references and files relating to `mod_jk` from `/etc/httpd/conf`, reinstalled CF then re-ran the connector.

It's installed successfully with this command:

```
$ sudo ./wsconfig -ws Apache -dir /etc/httpd/conf
```

I have the dir at `/opt/coldfusion2018/config/wsconfig/1` setup but I'm now getting these errors:

```
$ pwd
/opt/coldfusion2018/config/wsconfig/1

$ tail mod_jk.log
[error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (3000): (cfusion) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=583, client_errors=0).
[info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (816): connect to ::1:8018 failed (errno=13)
[info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1140): (cfusion) Failed opening socket to (::1:8018) (errno=13)
[error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1811): (cfusion) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
[info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2979): (cfusion) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=1)
[info] jk_open_socket::jk_connect.c (816): connect to ::1:8018 failed (errno=13)
[info] ajp_connect_to_endpoint::jk_ajp_common.c (1140): (cfusion) Failed opening socket to (::1:8018) (errno=13)
[error] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1811): (cfusion) connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port (errno=13)
[info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2979): (cfusion) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending (attempt=2)
[error] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (3000): (cfusion) connecting to tomcat failed (rc=-3, errors=584, client_errors=0).
```

I have no idea where port 8018 has come from, I thought tomcat used 8500 by default

**UPDATE 2**

If I visit my site with `:8500` on the end I can get into the CFIDE, so it's CF is running and that port is accessible

**UPDATE 3**

I've found this in my `server.xml` file, tried setting the port to both 8009 and 8018 and it seems to make no difference to the errors in the mod_jk.log

```
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
        <!-- begin connector -->
    <Connector port="8009" packetSize="65535" protocol="AJP/1.3"  redirectPort="8451" tomcatAuthentication="false" maxThreads="500" connectionTimeout="60000"/>
    <!-- end connector -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was SELinux blocking port 8018, I actually asked my hosting provider Secura to look into this for me and they fixed it (based on all the information I'd found from piyush's answer)

I had to allow port 8018 in SELinux

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8018
```

Answer (score 1):

Pete,

What's the OS and the webserver's version?

Did you try passing the parameters other than dir, explicitly, like so:

```
sudo ./wsconfig -ws Apache /opt/apache2/conf -bin /opt/apache2/bin/httpd -script /opt/apache2/bin/apachectl -dir -v
```

..and the coldfusion process need not be running for the connector to be configured.

Comment: so I deleted everything from `/etc/httpd/conf` to do with modjk, reinstalled cf and re-ran the connector.

I'm now getting an error I was getting much earlier on on about tomcat possibly listening on the wrong port.

I'll update the answer and add version numbers as well

Comment: oh I only just noticed that last bit! will stop CF, remove and re-add the connector then start it up again

Comment: still no luck. good reminder though... silly of me not to stop CF first

Answer (score 1):

8018 is the default AJP port that the conector uses to talk to tomcat. 8500 is the default HTTP port that you'd use when you access the CF admin console.
You initially reported error when configuring the connector. Is that resolved.
Did you check the wsconfig log to see if there were errors configuring the connector.

The modjk log excrepts you've shared more recently simply indicate that CF is not running, or at the least, not listening on the default AJP port.

Comment: This post is actually my original error, in trying to fix it I broke some things and ended up getting the errors in my previous post (talking about the apache path when runnign wsconfig). I cleared everything out and started fresh and I am back at this point.

I can access my CFIDE via port 8500 and I can access simple HTML pages served via apache. When accessing CF pages via apache errors appear in the `/config/wsconfig/1/mod_jk.log`, which are now posted in the question. The wsconfig.log doesn't have any errors in since I cleared everything out and started again, it all looks successful

Comment: `not listening on the default AJP port.` so CF is running as I can get into the admin panel, how do I get it to listen on the AJP port? I've left all port numbers as defaults during the setup

Comment: well, did you check (with a relevant linux command like netstat) if the port 8018 is open and tied to CF's process ID. If it is not, can you check the AJP connector config in CF's server.xml. It should be uncommented  and  set to the right port no. I'm assuming here that both CF and HTTPD are one the same host.

Comment: server.xml has this line, not commented out: `<Connector port="8018" packetSize="65535" protocol="AJP/1.3"  redirectPort="8451" tomcatAuthentication="false" maxThreads="500" connectionTimeout="60000"/>`

Comment: `netstat -l | ack 8018` shows me `tcp6 0 0 [::]:8018 [::]:* LISTEN` but I don't know what that means

Comment: you can get the CF's process ID with the command: ps -ef | grep coldfusion. 
use the PID from the output to fetch all the open ports associated with that process with the command: netstat -anp | grep <PID>
If 8018 is not in use with CF's PID than there's the fault.
In case that looks good then try digging deeper by enabling the verbose logging in mod_jk.conf, the CF connector config file, by changing the log level to debug.
After enabling debug log, restart the webserver, hit a cfm page and examine the log file again.

Comment: sorry for taking ages to get back, thanks for all this. Netstat shows port 8018 (and others) being used by my CF process, so I'll have a look at the logging via mod jk

Comment: so I don't have a global mod_jk log, I've tried changing the path from `/etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.log` to `/var/log/httpd/mod_jk.log` but I can't see a log being created anywhere